# Listener not reacting to second call

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to learn Kotlin and I'm writing code to test and confirm my understanding.  In the result of the following code, I expect to see "Property age changed from 37 to 38" near the end.  Why am I not seeing that.

I tried writing the increment to age as age.plus initially, but that made the same result.

```
package ch07.ImplementingDelegatedProperties

import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener

open class PropertyChangeAware {
    protected val changeSupport = PropertyChangeSupport(this)

    fun addPropertyChangeListener(listener: PropertyChangeListener) {
        changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener)
    }

    fun removePropertyChangeListener(listener: PropertyChangeListener) {
        changeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener)
    }
}

class Person(
    val name: String, age: Int?, salary: Int
)
    : PropertyChangeAware()
{

    var age: Int? = age
        set(newValue) {
            println("age changed")

            val oldValue = field
            field = newValue
            changeSupport.firePropertyChange(
                "age", oldValue, newValue)
        }

    var salary: Int = salary
        set(newValue) {
            val oldValue = field
            field = newValue
            changeSupport.firePropertyChange(
                "salary", oldValue, newValue)
        }

    operator fun plus (older: Int) :Person {
        println("age changed by operator")
        val oldValue = age
        val newValue = (oldValue?: 0) + older
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange( // don't know why this dosn't fire repeatedly
            "age", oldValue, newValue)
        println("age chg by operator, $oldValue -> $newValue")
        this.age = (oldValue?: 0) + older
        // this._attributes = _attributes
        return Person(name, age = age, salary = salary)
    }

}



fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var p = Person("Dmitry", 34, 2000)
    p.addPropertyChangeListener(
        PropertyChangeListener { event ->
            println("Property ${event.propertyName} changed " +
                    "from ${event.oldValue} to ${event.newValue}")
        }
    )
    println(p.age)
    p.age = 35
    println(p.age.toString())
    p.age = 36
    println(p.age.toString())
    p = p + 1
    println(p.age.toString())
    p = p + 1
    println(p.age.toString())
    p.salary = 2100
}
```

Actual results:

```
34
age changed
Property age changed from 34 to 35
35
age changed
Property age changed from 35 to 36
36
age changed by operator
Property age changed from 36 to 37
age chg by operator, 36 -> 37
age changed
Property age changed from 36 to 37
37
age changed by operator
age chg by operator, 37 -> 38
age changed
38
```

Expected results:

```
34
age changed
Property age changed from 34 to 35
35
age changed
Property age changed from 35 to 36
36
age changed by operator
Property age changed from 36 to 37
age chg by operator, 36 -> 37
age changed
Property age changed from 36 to 37
37
age changed by operator
age chg by operator, 37 -> 38
age changed
Property age changed from 37 to 38  << This line expected but not appearing
38
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, at the end of your `plus` function, you create a brand new `Person` object (which copies the `name` and `salary` and increases the `age`) but importantly, it has a new `changeSupport` object which you haven't run    `addPropertyChangeListener` on.

It looks like `PropertyChangeSupport` allows you to have no listeners defined, so won't error or give you a clue that there is not listener

Comment: You are a genius.  That worked perfectly.  I created the new person and added the listener to it all while inside the plus function and then returned the new person with the listener already attached.